# How do I create clickable areas on an sap.m.Image element?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

There is an old example on the SAPUI5 website to create an image with clickable areas. But [that example](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/ImageMap.html) talks about the `sap.ui.commons.Image` element which is not (recommended to be) used anymore.

Nowadays we use controls from the mobile library in fiori-style applications. I tried to employ the `ImageMap` control from the `commons` library along with an `sap.m.Image`element but couldn't get it to work.

1. How to exploit the `useMap` property of the `sap.m.Image` control?
2. If there is not enough native support, what external library can I use to display an interactive image parts of which can be clicked (and if possible highlighted)?

This is more or less what I tried doing -

XML View:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="myApp.view.Image" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true">
    <Page title="Human Body">
        <Panel class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" width="auto">
            <content>
                <Image id="human" src="images/human_body.png" alt="" useMap="bodyFunctions"></Image>        
            </content>
        </Panel>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/commons/ImageMap",
    "sap/ui/commons/Area"
], function(Controller, ImageMap, Area) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("myApp.view.Image", {
        onInit: function() {
            this._oView = this.getView();
            this._humanImage = this._oView.byId("human");
            var oImageMap = new ImageMap({
                name: "bodyFunctions",
                areas: [new Area("Area1", {
                    shape: "rect",
                    alt: "Brain",
                    coords: "566,4,343,52"
                })],
                press: function(oEvent) {
                    alert("You've clicked on brain");
                }
            });
            this._oView.addContent(oImageMap);
        }
    });
});
```

P.S: I don't have to show a geographical map. I have to highlight parts of an object.

Thanks.

Comment: good question, commons.ImageMap is deprecated in 1.38, inside m.Image there is a TODO for the new m.ImageMap

Comment: So, is there another way to accomplish this? Maybe using an external library?

Answer (score 0):

While that doesn't answer the part of your question about highlighting the areas in the image, here's how you can provide a map as the `useMap` parameter for a `sap.m.image`:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="xy.controller.Master" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" >
  <App>
    <pages>
      <Page title="{i18n>title}">
        <content>
          <Image src="img/Blume.PNG" densityAware="false" width="" useMap="Map">
            <layoutData>
              <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
            </layoutData>
          </Image>

          <html:map name="Map" id="Map">
            <html:area alt="" title="" href="www.google.de" shape="poly" coords="384,505,444,507,444,528,390,527"/>
            <html:area alt="" title="" href="www.google.de" shape="poly" coords="426,582,494,583,494,636,426,632"/>
          </html:map>

        </content>
      </Page>
    </pages>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Note the declaration of the `html` namespace at the top: `xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Credits: https://answers.sap.com/questions/290270/how-use-sapmimage-with-usemap-and-get-the-clicked.html